# Cascading dropdown list

Tags: list, custom-list, dropdown, cascading

I have created a cascading dropdown list in sharepoint. My problem is, after I select my parent column, the subsequent child column does not change to match it.
For example: I select Australia from a drop down, the states drop down has Vic, NSW etc. When I change the country drop down to USA, the states drop down still has VIC, NSW etc.

Comment: How did you create it? SharePoint out of the box does not support cascading drop downs - you need JavaScript code to do it. What does your code look like?

Comment: Yeah I did add some code. I followed the site https://www.youtube.com/watchv=Q0L9cnSvVjA   which shows the code they add at the 4 minute mark, and again at the 8 minute mark

Comment: How did you create it? Can you share some code or tell us how you did it?

Comment: <script src=”//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js”></script>

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js                                                                                           <script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: “Sub Competency”,
 relationshipListParentColumn: “Competency”,
 relationshipListChildColumn: “Title”,
 parentColumn: “Competency”,
 childColumn: “Sub Competency”,
 debug: true
})
})
</script>

Comment: have you used SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Comment: is that a website or piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using article.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({

```
        relationshipList: "states",

        relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",

        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",

        parentColumn: "Country",

        childColumn: "State",

        debug: true
    });

   $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "City",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "State",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "State",
        childColumn: "City",
        debug: true
    });
```

});